# Firebase usage with service worker

Tags: firebase, performance, hosting, service-worker, usage-statistics

I recently hosted a website for events on Firebase hosting and have not been able to see what will be the monthly usage of the app. I have a service worker that caches the files of the website for faster subsequent visits and offline capability. **My question is, can the service worker reduce the monthly firebase usage of the website as the website will be loaded most of the times from the cache and not from a request to firebase?** This is purely my way of thinking so correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will reduce the usage.

The usage is displayed in the firebase console => Hosting => Usage => Downloads (Bytes sent)